# Inconsistent Tally Using vectors and pthreads

Tags: c++, pthreads

So I'm working on a simple program to tally votes from multiple text files (each line of each file containing the name of one of the candidates, representing one vote).

I have it mostly working, with one remaining problem: The total number of votes for each candidate is inaccurate for a given candidate unless that candidate has the exact same number of votes in *each* `votes.txt` file. Order doesn't make a difference.

For example: if `votes1.txt` is the only file in the target directory, and has 1 vote for each of the candidates:

```
votes1.txt:

Clinton
Cruz
Kasich
Sanders
Trump
```

the final tally the program produces will correctly have 1-vote for each every time I run the program.

Similarly, if the target directory has `votes1.txt` and `votes2.txt` and each has 1 vote for each candidate (in any order), the final tally will correctly have 2-votes for each.

However as soon as the text files start having different numbers of votes for the candidates I start getting incorrect and inconsistent totals in the final tally.

EG: If the contents of `votes1.txt` and `votes2.txt` are as follows:

```
votes1.txt:

Clinton
Cruz
Kasich
Sanders
Trump

votes2.txt:

Clinton
Cruz
Kasich
Clinton
Sanders
Trump
```

The final tally will not be correct for Clinton (in this case it will still be 2 instead of 3). But if the files both had 2 votes for Clinton, the final tally would be correct once more with a total of 4 votes for Clinton and 2-each for the rest. The final totals only get farther and farther off the mark the larger and more disparate the `votes.txt` files get.

It's a very odd and specific error but combing through my code I just can't pinpoint what's causing it.

Here's the relevant code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<string> voteTallyFiles;
    vector<voteTally> intermVoteTallies;
    voteTally finalVoteTally;
    string args;
    voteTally returnValue;
    void *returnValueP;
    void *argp;
    int index = 0;

    //Grab vote tally files from Target Directory
    getFileNames(voteTallyFiles);

    vector<pthread_t> threads(voteTallyFiles.size());

    //Count the votes using pthreads and a thread function
    for (vector<pthread_t>::iterator iter = threads.begin(); iter != threads.end(); ++iter, index++)
    {
        args = voteTallyFiles[index];
        argp = &args;
        pthread_create(&*iter, NULL, &countVotes, argp);
    }

    // Wait for the threads
    for (vector<pthread_t>::iterator iter = threads.begin(); iter != threads.end(); ++iter)
    {
        pthread_join(*iter, &returnValueP);
        returnValue = *((voteTally*)returnValueP);
        intermVoteTallies.push_back(returnValue);
    }   

    // Aggregate sub-tallies
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < intermVoteTallies.size(); i++)
    {
        finalVoteTally.pres1 += intermVoteTallies[i].pres1;
        finalVoteTally.pres2 += intermVoteTallies[i].pres2;
        finalVoteTally.pres3 += intermVoteTallies[i].pres3;
        finalVoteTally.pres4 += intermVoteTallies[i].pres4;
        finalVoteTally.pres5 += intermVoteTallies[i].pres5;
    }

    return 0;
}

void* countVotes(void *argp)
{
    string* actualArgs = (string*)argp;
    string fileName = *actualArgs;

    string line;
    ifstream inFile;
    voteTally *subTally = new voteTally;

    inFile.open(fileName.c_str());

    while (getline(inFile, line))
    {
        if (line == PRES1)
        {
            subTally->pres1++;
        }
        else if (line == PRES2)
        {
            subTally->pres2++;
        }
        else if (line == PRES3)
        {
            subTally->pres3++;
        }
        else if (line == PRES4)
        {
            subTally->pres4++;
        }
        else if (line == PRES5)
        {
            subTally->pres5++;
        }
    }
    return subTally;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one problem:

```
args = voteTallyFiles[index];
argp = &args;
pthread_create(&*iter, NULL, &countVotes, argp);
```

In the lines above you pass `argp` to the threads, but they are all pointing to the exact same local variable, `args`, meaning that all threads might use the same data.

Instead pass a pointer to `voteTallyFiles[index]` using the address-of operator:

```
pthread_create(&*iter, NULL, &countVotes, &voteTallyFiles[index]);
```

Comment: You're brilliant. Completely fixed it. This is my first time programming with threads so I'm still developing a sense of what to look for. Much thanks!